# Is it possible to assign new value to C++ vector in O(1) time?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, reference

## **Consider the following Python program with the following steps:**

1) Two lists A and B are initialized.

2) We assign A = B. The time complexity of this operation is O(1).

3) We assign a new list to B which does not change A.

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
B = [7, 8]
# A contains [1, 2, 3]
# B contains [7, 8]

#------------------------------------

A = B
# A contains [7, 8]
# B contains [7, 8]
# time complexity: O(1)

#------------------------------------

B = [55, 66, 77, 88]
# A still contains [7, 8]
# B now contains [55, 66, 77, 88]
```

## **Now, I want to do something similar in C++ where A and B are vectors:**

1) Two vectors A and B are initialized.

2) We assign A = B. The time complexity of this operation is O(n) according to [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).

3) We assign a new list to B which does not change A.

```
vector<int> A = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> B = {7, 8};
// A contains [1, 2, 3]
// B contains [7, 8]


A = B;   
// A contains [7, 8]
// B contains [7, 8]
// time complexity: O(n)


B = {55, 66, 77, 88};
// A still contains [7, 8]
// B now contains [55, 66, 77, 88]
```

**My question**

The difference between the Python and C++ program is the time complexity of step 2) where we assign A = B.

- In Python it takes O(1) time because we only change a reference. A then 'points to' B, i.e. A and B are both references to the same object.
- In C++ it takes O(n) time because the content of B is copied to A. A does not 'point to' the same object as B.

Is there any way to make the vector A in C++ point to the vector B in O(1) time?

Note: I'm not very familiar with C++ and so I don't even know if it's valid to consider A and B as references to vector objects in C++.

Comment: Python variables are basically *pointers*. Perhaps you wanted to make `A` and `B` pointers in C++ too?

Comment: While C++ have references, they can't be used in the same way, as a reference in C++ can't be "reassigned". Once initialized, a reference will always reference what it initially was initialized to. The only solution to change "references" is to use pointers, but then you have to use pointer-dereference when doing something simple as indexing the vector. So in short no, there's no way for C++ to do anything similar to Python.

Comment: You can use pointer and dynamically allocated memory. Then you just have to make sure you delete A before making it point to B.

Comment: There is also another solution, and that is to use a wrapper-class for `std::vector`, that internally uses pointers to vectors. That requires you to reimplement the `std::vector` interface though, but for most of the functions it would just be a simple inline function that calls the container vectors corresponding function.

Comment: Python idioms do not necessarily translate well to C++. If you are writing C++ code, write it in C++, aka "when in Rome, do as Romans do".

Comment: Thank you for all your comments! I think I will go with [el.pescado's suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36616376/4019402) below of using `std::move()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you don't use value of `B` after assigning it to `A` (you assign to it directly afterwards) you can take advantage of C++11 move semantics:

```
vector<int> A = {1, 2, 3};
vector<int> B = {7, 8};
A = std::move(B);
// O(1), see below
// B is in indeterminate but usable state now (probably empty).

B = {55, 66, 77, 88};
// A still contains [7, 8]
// B now contains [55, 66, 77, 88]
```

Time complexity of move assignment operator is:

> Constant unless `std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::propagate_on_container_move_assignment()`
>   is `false` and the allocators do not compare equal (in which case
>   linear).

[source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @el.pescado. Using `std::move()` works for me, although I have to admit that I could not understand that it takes constant time because I'm not familiar with allocators.

Comment: using `std::swap` is more explicit