# C++ "[ ]" operator

Tags: c++, time-complexity, operators

I recently read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615792/is-it-possible-to-assign-new-value-to-c-vector-in-o1-time) question, and on searching a bit I [found](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D) that for vectors(any many more containers) `[ ]` operator in c++
actually returns reference and thus O(1) complexity , just [above](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/) it, it is mentioned that `=` operator has linear time complexity, so my question is if I have a multidimensional vector v and I do something like :

```cpp
v[i]=v[j];
```

will it be constant time operation or linear time and why? somewhere I have read it's O(1) but I am not sure.

[This](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/67696?#comment-519009) was the blog in which an algorithm was being discussed, and in this comment's second line the user said it's O(1)(here v is an multidimensional vector/ array of vector), and it's the key thing in this algorithm, if it's not, I think the algorithm won't be of same complexity,

Thanks!

Comment: [`std::vector::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) costs linear time.

Comment: @Old Man You need to copy all elements of the vector v[j] to the vector v[i]. What will be the complexity?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It will be linear.

Comment: @OldMan So you just answered your own question ;)

Comment: @OldMan Thanks. I will know.

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes, I have written that in my post, if it was for vectors u and v then u=v is linear, but here v[j] is reference to the vector at j, it's the reason for my doubt.

Comment: What is "vector" here? If it is your own vector, not `std::vector`, and supports efficient "copy" (like updating only reference at assign and perform actual copy when something is written), it may be constant time.

Comment: @MikeCAT it's C++ std::vector.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I didn't get what you meant in your second comment.

Comment: I have added link to the blog which I was referring.

Comment: When you say that something is `O(f(n))`, it matters which `n` you're talking about. If you have `vector<vector<T>> v; vector<T> x;`, `v[i] = x` is constant in the size of `v`, and linear in the size of `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copying of an entire `std::vector<T>` is O(N) as each element `T` needs to be copied.

All overloads of `std::vector<T>::operator[]` are required by the C++ standard to have constant complexity. Normally it's implemented using pointer arithmetic on the data in the `std::vector`.

So, `v[i] = v[j];` is O(1).

The fact that `T` could be arbitrarily multidimensional does not matter here. A vector copy is O(N) since if you double the number of elements, you double the time (in some limit anyway). The vector *element* copy is O(1) since it does not depend on the number of elements in the vector.

Comment: But if `T` is also a `std::vector`, then it will be O(N) again ;) But this N is related to length of this "internal" vector, not to "external" vector.

Comment: @Bathsheba your v is same as mine right? multidimensional?

Comment: @OldMan, look at this in following way. `=` for fixed size object is O(1), but for variable size object it is O(N). So, if we have `std::vector<T>` where `T` is fixed size type, then `v[i] = v[j]` is O(1), but if `T` is variable size type, like `std::vector`, then `v[i] = v[j]` is O(N).

Comment: @sklott -- the time to execute `v[i] = v[j]` does not depend on the size of `v`. That makes it constant time. If you double the size of `v` the time to do the assignment stays the same. Yes, the time needed to copy an element might vary, but that's a property of the element, not the container.

Comment: @OldMan: See the final paragraph I've added. Although I think PeteBecker puts it in a better way.

Comment: @Bathsheba Sorry, but I am confused, so answer to my question is, "Yes,It's O(1)" right? You said vector copy is O(N), here v[i] and v[j] are vector itself, and in next line said they are vector<T> 's element(vector elements) so O(1) ?

Comment: @OldMan: Yes you do seem to be in a pickle. With respect to the overall container, the assignment is O(1). It doesn't matter what the vector payload is. Pete Becker puts this in a clear way.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm not good with these O-notations, so probably my intent was not so clear. Let me try to rephrase it. What I was trying to say, is that `v[i] = v[j]` complexity doesn't depend from size of vector `v`, but it **does** depend from size of `T`. And if `T` is another `std::vector` then complexity will be O(N), where N - characteristic of `T`, not `v`.

Comment: @sklott — when you increase the size of the vector from `k` to `k * N`, the time needed for `v[i] = v[k]` does not change. So its complexity is O(1); it is not O(N). If you keep the vector size the same and fiddle with the element, yes, the time needed can change. But that’s not a measure of the behavior of the vector, since it happens without changing the size of the vector.